# JSDoc for Lambda function in object

Tags: javascript, tags, documentation, jsdoc

I need to use JSDoc to make `sock`, `data` variables known

```
var exec = {
    /**
     * @param {Number} sock
     * @param {String} data
     */
    1: (sock, data) => {
        console.log("GG");
    },
    2: (sock, data) => {

    },
    3: (sock, data) => {

    }
};
```

let's say **sock** is `Number`, and **data** is `String`.

```
/**
 * @param {Number} sock
 * @param {String} data
 */
```

I need to set the JSDoc one time only, for the whole object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
/**
 * @type {Object.<number, function(Object, Object):void>}
 */
var exec = {
    1: (sock, data) => {
        console.log("GG");
    },
    2: (sock, data) => {

    },
    3: (sock, data) => {

    }
};
```

This defines an object with numbers as keys and functions as values which takes two params of type Object.

The Syntax compiles from

`Object.<[keyType, valueType]>`

and

`function(param1Type, param2Type, ...):returnType`